# Crystal Report: If-Else If Formula

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-server

For one string field in crystal report i wish to write up formula where if that field is null, it should display as "No value" else  the actual values should come up

What i have written is

Local StringVar x;
If {mysp;1.mystringfield} ="" or IsNull({mysp;1.mystringfield}) then
x := "No value";
**Else
x := {mysp;1.mystringfield}**

The bold marked shows error saying "the remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula crystal reports"

Whats incorrect in my formula?

Let me know for more inputs

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to remove the `;` and wrap the or in brackets:

```
Local StringVar x; 

If (IsNull({mysp;1.mystringfield}) or {mysp;1.mystringfield} ="") then 
x := "No value"
Else x := {mysp;1.mystringfield}
```

Comment: @Barry: Thanks for the help... that actually worked!. but the report doesn't display No Value where there is no value. However the else condition do works!

Comment: are you displaying x on the report or the field value?

Comment: @Beth: I am displaying field value

Comment: @Romil - So you are displaying the formula on the report not the field from your Stored Proc?

Comment: @Barry: I am displaying the formula on report

Comment: @Romil - I believe you need to do the NULL check first, or even separately; if the mysp;1.mystringfield is NULL, the rest of the formula short circuits and returns nothing.

Comment: @Romil - you just need to move the IsNull check to be the first thing to check.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF Isnull({mysp;1.mystringfield}) Then
  "No Value"
Else
  {mysp;1.mystringfield}
```